# why deparse(substitute(x)) not picking the name of 'x'

Tags: r, function, arguments, evaluation

I was wondering why `deparse(substitute(x))` for my `xlab` does not put the name of `x` for `xlab` as expected (*see picture below*)?

```
gg <- function(x, xlab = deparse(substitute(x)), ylab = NA, freq = FALSE, ...) { 
    x <- round(x)
    ylab <- if(is.na(ylab) & freq) {
        "Frequency" 
    } else if(is.na(ylab) & !freq) {
        "Probability" 
    } else ylab
    z <- if(freq) table(x) else table(x)/length(x)
    plot(z, xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab, ...)
}

# Example of use:
gg(mtcars$gear)    # 'mtcars' is a base R built-in dataset
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is lazy evaluation. (Don't ask me to explain the details, please. It's complicated and you can study this with the [language definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html). But basically, `x` is modified before `xlab` is evaluated.) You can fix this easily by using `force`:

```
gg <- function(x, xlab = deparse(substitute(x)), ylab = NA, freq = FALSE, ...) {
  force(xlab)
  x <- round(x)
  ylab <- if(is.na(ylab) & freq) "Frequency" else if(is.na(ylab) & !freq) "Probability" else ylab
  z <- if(freq) table(x) else table(x)/length(x)
  plot(z, xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab, ...)
}
# Example of use:
gg(mtcars$gear)
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Alternatively, I think maybe a more common pattern would be to have `xlab = NULL` by default, and then have the first line of the function check if it's null, and if so, do the `deparse(substitute())` at that point.

Comment: @joran or use no default and `if(missing(xlab)) xlab <- ...` as the first line,

Comment: Since `force` is just another name for `identity`, you *could* just put `xlab` on the first line of the function. It looks funny, though, so the syntactic sugar is nice to show why it's necessary.